# Rajorpay Integration Not Working in flutter Project

Tags: flutter, geolocator

After update Latest Version of Flutter,I am using Geolocator And razorpay_flutter in flutter Project.then project was not  run. give this issue:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on RMX1925 in debug mode...
```

```
main.dart:1
```

```
Parameter format not correct -
```

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

```
D/FlutterGeolocator(20783): Attaching Geolocator to activity
```

```
Exited (sigterm)
```

```
Exited (sigterm)
```